# Active vs. passive: "waves are formed by" vs. "waves formed by"

Tags: active-vs-passive

> Mostly, waves ... by wind blowing over the surface of the sea.

A) **are formed** *( my answer )*

B) **formed** *( correct according to my book )*

Should I burn my book ?

Comment: Background and context required. What book is this exactly? And is the sentence complete?

Comment: I assume that the first word is actually "Mostly"?

Comment: I shortened it by not giving all of options  and l just realized  miswriting 'ostly' instead of mostly

Answer (score 3):

They are both correct, but "are formed" is much better, for several reasons:

- wave-forming is a continuous process; "formed" implies that the process already finished;
- "are formed" is proper passive voice, which is correlated tot he reality; "formed" is a kind of middle-voice reflexive something.

Even the following is better than simply "formed":

> Mostly, waves **were formed** by wind blowing over the surface of the sea.

Bottom line: your choice was the better choice.

---

> Should I burn my book?

Definitely not. That is a useless process, and it only creates pollution. You can save the book and use the pages one by one, on an as-needed basis, to start camp fires - please attend those fires responsibly, you do not want to burn the entire planet.

Comment: This is just a joke but  you are really sensitive to the environment . I appreciate it and thank everbody for help

Comment: Yes, the second part is a joke. I suppose it was a joke also when you asked about burning the book :)